# Standard Python module not available in Pycharm project interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pycharm

Is it correct to say that Pycharm project interpretor does not show standard Python modules like datetime, bisect,heapq etc? how can I import them?
Or am i missing something ?

Comment: First of all, did you set the interpreter for the project?

Answer (score 0):

Nope its not correct to say that.

There might be some problem displaying those module names in auto complete help.

But if you cannot import standar modules please try checking you PYTHONPATH and python interpreter selected in pycharm.